# How I can create a spring bed sound like in the following songs?

Tags: ableton, sound-design

How can I create a spring sound like in the following songs?

Comment: full youtube links displays a player. Best.

Answer (score 1):

For Madonna you can check [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u06TOaP4UJc) which pretty much explains the basis of how to make this type of sound which is by the way a, let say, "Brass Trap" sound more than a spring sound. Pay a special attention to few things on this sound :

- Portamento/Bending
- The Density

For the second track, they've probably made it by recording different spring sounds (from the same source), then cutted the source into samples in order to make a ryhtm with it, they' ve probably also corrected the tune of the sound. This is really easy to do so by using samplers like [Native Instruments - Kontakt](http://www.native-instruments.com/en/products/komplete/samplers/kontakt-5/whats-new/)

So just to be clear, first sound is a synth and second is a recording, so not the same technique to make it and not the same sound.

Hope this helped,